# Reading html page string as dataframe with Python

Tags: python, html, dataframe

I have an HTML page with a string. I want to convert it into a dataframe. The rows in this string are separated with a space that is not inside the quotes (there are spaces between quotes in column values).

The page: https://gladys.geog.ucl.ac.uk/bikesapi/load.php?scheme=saopaulo

I tried several solutions, but nothing matched my problem.

Comment: Could you add a relevant sample of the page's HTML to your question? I am conscious that the Gladys page might change in the future, and the question will have limited value if people can't see what it looked like at the time it was answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `pd.read_csv`:

```py
url = "https://gladys.geog.ucl.ac.uk/bikesapi/load.php?scheme=saopaulo"

df = pd.read_csv(url)
print(df.head())
```

Prints:

```
   #id timestamp|gmt_local_diff_sec|gmt_servertime_diff_sec                   name        lat        lon  bikes  spaces  installed  locked  temporary  total_docks  givesbonus_acceptspedelecs_fbbattlevel  pedelecs
0    1                               1692123219|10800|-3600    1 - Largo da Batata -23.566831 -46.693741     43      37       True   False      False           83                                     NaN        10
1    3                               1692123219|10800|-3600     3 - CPTM Pinheiros -23.566478 -46.701258      6       7       True   False      False           15                                     NaN         3
2    4                               1692123219|10800|-3600  4 - Rua Diogo Moreira -23.569145 -46.692003      2      20       True   False      False           23                                     NaN         2
3    5                               1692123219|10800|-3600        5 - Chicão Vive -23.569894 -46.697897      4       7       True   False      False           11                                     NaN         1
4    6                               1692123219|10800|-3600        6 - Rua Manduri -23.572137 -46.690107     10       7       True   False      False           19                                     NaN         0
```